# pandas hasnan() on Series gives "TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, null, nan

In my tests I have a method check_nulls to check specific columns for nulls

```
def check_nulls(self, name, column_list):
        """ Ensure that the table given has no nulls in any of the listed columns
            @param name the name of the table to check
            @param column_list the columns to check for nulls
        """
        df =  util.TABLES.load_table(name,
                                            config.get_folder("TRANSFORMED_FOLDER"),
                                     sep='|')
        #print df
        for column in column_list:
            print df[column].dtypes
            print df[column]
            self.assertFalse(df[column].dtypes != "int32" 
                                and df[column].dtypes != "int64" 
                                and df[column].hasnans(),
                             '{0} in {1} contains null values'\
                             .format(column, name))
```

The error is happening in df[column].hasnans() It gives me a typeError on some tables.

```
TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not callable
```

At first I thought it was an issue with int columns having no real null and since if they had a null they would have been converted to a float column I added that exemption from the check but I am now running into a column with a dtype of "object" that is giving me the error as well.

How can I properly check for nulls in a column on my dataframe? I checked the type of df[column] and it is in fact a Series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasnans` is a simple boolean value, not a method, so you can't call it.

However, I don't think this is a reliable way to determine whether a Series contains nans.  It is not updated if you modify the Series:

```
>>> x = pandas.Series([1, 2, 3])
>>> x.hasnans
False
>>> x[1] = np.nan
>>> x
0     1
1   NaN
2     3
dtype: float64
>>> x.hasnans
False
```

To check if a Series contains nans, use `if mySeries.isnull().any()`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I feel silly about this but will leave the question up in case someone else makes the same stupid mistake.

hasnans is a boolean not a function the solution is to not try to call it

df[column].hasnans not df[column].hasnans()